Problem in $p$-adic convergence of $p$-adic logarithm and $p$-adic exponential
I was studying a little bit of $p$-adic analysis and I came across $p$-adic logarithm and $p$-adic exponential. More specifically I saw that exists a theorem which states that on the disk of radius $p^{-1/(p-1)}$ these two functions are two bijections that are mutually inverse. However, the proof that I saw (which for reference is Neal Koblitz $p$-adic numbers, $p$-adic analysis, and Zeta-Functions second edition, Chapter IV p. 81) of this theorem uses the fact that, as formal power series in $\mathbb Q[[X]]$, the equalities $\log(\exp(X))=X$ and $\exp(\log(1+X))=1+X$ hold, so these are identities whenever the series converge. Unfortunately I discovered that in the case $p=2$ if we consider $x=2 \in \mathbb Z_2$, $\log_2(1+x)$ converges to a value $\alpha$ and that $\exp_2(\alpha)$ converge to a value $\beta$ which is different from $1+x=3$, so in this case $\exp_2(\log_2(1+x)) \ne 1+x$ even if the series both converge. What is the main problem in using this argument?

What is your argument that $\exp_2(\alpha)\ne3$? Also double check that the conditions in the theorem are really satisfied (they are not)

@leoli1 you can explicitly calculate it or if you don't want you can check it on Sage Math. I know that in that specific case all the conditions are not satisfied. The question is why, if both the series converge in this context, I can't conclude that the value where they converge is 3 even if in formal series we have that formal identity

I see, yes I now also checked it, interesting question!

See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf, in particular example 8.14.

It seems the problem is that the implication '$f = g\circ h \implies f(x) = g(h(x))$ when the expressions converge' (where $f,g,h$ are formal power series) is somewhat delicate and actually not necessarily true, but in the book this seems to be used without further justification. In addition to Torsten's reference also take a look at Robert's `P-adical Analysis' p. 294

@TorstenSchoeneberg thank you, your reference explains perfectly this example

@leoli1 thank you too, I read an interesting proposition about when it is possible to do the substitution

You're welcome. By the way, a simpler example for the phenomenon (in $2$-adics) would be $x=-2$, i.e. $\mathrm{exp}(\mathrm{log}(\color{red}{-}1))=\mathrm{exp}(0)=\color{red}{+}1$.

See also Theorem 8.13 at the same link Torsten gives. I learned $p$-adic analysis by Koblitz's book and enjoyed the experience, but on the issue of formal to numerical convergence for power series composition the justification in the book felt suspicious to me as a student.  A counterexample that works for all $p$ is $\exp(\log(1+X)) = 1+X$ and $x = \zeta_p - 1$ where $\zeta_p$ is a nontrivial $p$th root of unity (you need to use an extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ to access $\zeta_p$ when $p>2$). The left side at $x$ is $\exp(\log(\zeta_p))=\exp(0)=1$ and the right side at $x$ is $\zeta_p\not=1$.
